# Visual Studio не видит .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Не могу выбрать более поздние версии .NET Framework при создании нового проекта/редактировании свойств уже существующих, при том, что они установлены.
Использую Visual Studio Community 2015 (14.0.25123.00 Update 2)

[image: Создание проекта]

[image: Установленные программы]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12.06.16

[Targeting .NET Platforms](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html). Тут можно скачать компоненты платформы, если что-то не установилось по умолчанию.

Также попасть на страницу можно кликув "Другие платформы" в списке выбора платформы.

Студия самостоятельно определяет установленные фреймворки и их версии запрашивая сведения у системы. После установки платформы и студии может требоваться перезагрузка системы, чтобы все необходимые изменения были обнаружены. Вообще проблема довольно странная, и возможно связана с некорректной установкой студии. На Win7 и VS2013 и более ранних такого ни разу не наблюдал.

Также стоит попробовать переустановить .NET нужной версии.

Comment: Я отсюда как раз и скачивал. А где эти скрипты? Никаких "других платформ" там нет.

Comment: @aww "Другие платформы..." в выпадающем списке при создании проекта и в настройках, даже на скрине в вопросе вопросе видно. А со страницы по ссылке в ответе их надо для каждой платформы отдельно качать, там есть линки на *.vs файлы для всех платформ

Comment: хм... похоже был не прав... скриптов там правда нет. Может студия криво встала? Мне честно говоря ставить 2015 комьюнити поверх 2013 премиум стремно как-то. Можно попробовать переустановить фреймворк, но это может оказаться дольше чем переустановить студию...

Comment: @aww ребут после установки студии и фреймворков был?

Comment: При нажатии на "Другие платформы" открывает ту ссылку, что вы выше указали. Ребут делал. Попробую переустановить.

Comment: Переустановка всех версий .NET помогла.