# Проблема импорта некоторых System библиотек C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Я имею установленной Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 совсем недавно. При создании проекта, IDE шаблонно импортирует System.Linq в консольных и System.Linq, System.Data, System.Windows.Forms. Но эти строчки содержат ошибку (сразу при создании проекта) вида "Имя отсутствует в пространстве имен System.*". В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Причина ошибки - отсутствие ссылок на необходимые библиотечные сборки в проекте.

Ссылки могут отсутствовать по одной из двух причин, либо ошибка при установке студии и не корректно установленные шаблоны проектов, либо ошибка при установке фреймворка или его отсутствие.

Необходимые действия:

1. проверить что установлены все нужные версии .NET и доустановить нужное.
2. проверить наличие ссылок на необходимые сборки в проекте
3. если ссылки отсутствуют - добавить их руками и проверить.
4. если выяснится что проблема с шаблонами проектов - попробовать для начала `repaire` студии, если не помогло - переустановить студию.
5. Если не помогло выше перечисленное - стоит попробовать переустановить проблемную версию .NET, возможно что-то не правильно установилось в нем.

Comment: Благодарю, но проблема была в требуемой версии framework в настройках проекта. По умолчанию 4.6.1 (которая у меня установлена), а вышеуказанные пространства имен появляются (внезапно) при требуемой версии 4.5.

Comment: @NikolayNIK эти пространства имен актуальны для всех версий начиная с 3.5 независимо от настроек проекта

Comment: Тем не менее, ошибка исчезла только при этом... .NET...

Comment: @NikolayNIK тогда попробуйте переставить фреймвок, который хотите использовать, возможно при установке что-то пошло не так. Тут уже попадался похожий вопрос, сейчас попробую найти

Comment: @NikolayNIK нашел http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523312/198316